# Asynchronously Insert Records to MsAccess

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I want to insert 2000 records into MsAccess Database. It works fine but it makes about 3 seconds delay in my form because of the insertion process. Is there a way to make the form not delaying, so it doesn't have to wait for the insertion process to finish to execute next statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many approaches to doing this by using a thread other than the ui thread. I'd recommend looking at [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx), [task parallel library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) or [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Each of those links will lead to plenty of examples of how to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: BackgroundWorker did it for me. Thanks